# Read integers from a file and pair them with next highest number

Tags: java

I have to read a file containing a list of numbers and then output for each number in the list, the next bigger number. For example, if the list is

```
78, 22, 56, 99, 12, 14, 17, 15, 1, 144, 37, 23, 47, 88, 3, 19
```

the output should look like the following:

```
78: 88
22: 23
144: max value
```

This is what i have so far

```
public class Numbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner fileScan;
        try {
            fileScan = new Scanner(new File("list.txt"));
            int data[][] = new int[10][];
            int row = 0;
            while(fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = fileScan.nextLine();
                String[] lineTokens = line.split(",");
                data[row] = new int[lineTokens.length];
                for (int col = 0; col<lineTokens.length; col++) {
                    data[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(lineTokens[col]);
                }
                row++;
            }
            for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col<data[row].length; col++) {
                    System.out.print(data[row][col]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting a null pointer exception for the ** ** line.

I am confused on how to arrange the array into a way where i can read the two integers in order to print out the correct values.

Comment: Your formatting is unfair to readers. I see no line with ** **. Please correct!

Answer (score 0):

Your NullPointerException is occurring in this section

```
for (row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
                //if (data[row] == null) continue;
                for (int col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
                    System.out.print(data[row][col] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
}
```

You allocate the array to be 10 in length, so data.length is 10, but data[row] is null if you don't have **row** number of lines in your file.

As for the other part of your question about arranging the numbers, I don't know what you're trying to achieve. If you can explain it better then I will edit the answer.